# Is there any prerequisite to using DISTINCT in GQL for GAE1.7.4?

Tags: google-app-engine, distinct, gql

I am trying to query a list of distinct properties over an ndb model from my Datastore via GQL.

My GQL query was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT property FROM AppUser ORDER BY property
```

After running this, I encountered the following error:

```
BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol SELECT
```

After checking the documentaion, I found that DISTINCT was only introduced in GAE 1.7.4, while the package I was using was GAE 1.7.3. I upgraded to the correct version and have confirmed that I am using the correct version number through the admin console. However, I am still getting the exact same error.

1) Is there some sort of prerequisite change I need to make to my application to activate the use of DISTINCT? 
2) Is there some other error I have overlooked in my query that causes it to fail?

Comment: Is distict part of  ndb?

Comment: I'm having similar problems with Query class `distinct` parameter (it's not working).

Comment: I think `DISTINCT` should come after the `property` though (seems that way from the docs anyway).

Comment: have you defined a composite index? https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes?hl=en_GB&_ga=1.173785572.67476826.1473260714